# Azure DevOps Implications of "include sub-areas"

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

I am using Area Path in Azure DevOps for categorization rather than breaking into separate Teams.  So I can't see all the Work Items underneath the Default Backlog.  I go into Settings and choose "Include Sub Areas" and I get the following Warning:

> Are you sure you want to include sub-areas?
>
> You have selected the root area path as your team's work area. This
> causes two things to happen:
>
> 1. All work items that appear on any team backlog will also appear on
>    your team's backlog.
> 2. All work items under this area path will be updated, which might
>    impact the performance of your server until the changes are complete.
>    Are you sure you want to do this? If not, choose Cancel, and the
>    change will not be made.

#1 is what I want, but what are the implications of #2?  What is updated on the Work Item?  Will the Assigned To user be emailed of the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #2. The items will be stackranked again to define the backlog order for all work items in the selection. I've seen instances that had millions of work items and the recalculation of the backlog priority field and mapping to your team's custom board columns may take a while in that case.

This field is excluded from the standard email notifications.